# multidimensional array to simple array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have an array like this

```
array(5) { 
    [0]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(5) "REFER" [1]=> string(12) "Não Sócios" } 
    [1]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(5) "REFER" [1]=> string(12) "Não Sócios" } 
    [2]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(5) "REFER" [1]=> string(12) "Não Sócios" } 
    [3]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(5) "REFER" [1]=> string(12) "Não Sócios" } 
    [4]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(5) "REFER" [1]=> string(12) "Não Sócios" } 
}
```

and want to transform this array into an array like this

```
array("REFER, Não Sócios", "REFER, Não Sócios", "REFER, Não Sócios", "REFER, Não Sócios", "REFER, Não Sócios");
```

is that possible? if so, how can i do it?
thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Assuming that array is called `$refer` -

```
$new_refer = array_map(function($val) {
    return implode(', ', $val);
}, $refer);
```

Using [parray_map](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) you iterate over the elements and construct a new array with values returned from the callback function. Inside that function i'm using [implode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) to combine the values of each element (which is an array in itself) and glue them with `', '`.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with `array_map` for example:

```
$r = array_map(function($v) { return $v[0] . ', ' . $v[1]; }, $source_array);
```

Answer (score -1):

here's a way you can do it:

```
$a = [
    [ 0 => "REFER", 1 => "Nao Socios" ] ,
    [ 0 => "REFER", 1 => "Nao Socios" ] , 
    [ 0 => "REFER", 1 => "Nao Socios" ] , 
    [ 0 => "REFER", 1 => "Nao Socios" ] ,
    [ 0 => "REFER", 1 => "Nao Socios" ] 
];
$res = [];

foreach ($a as $k => $v) {
    $res[] = $v[0];
    $res[] = $v[1];
}
var_dump($res);
```